# SQL query to select union of properties

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

There is a table:

```
ID    INDEX  PROPERTY  VALUE
-----------------------------
1      1      p1        v1
2      1      p3        v3
3      2      p2        v2
4      2      p3        v3a
5      3      p1        v1a
6      3      p2        v2a
7      3      p3        v3b
```

I need to select union of all PROPERTY where INDEX=1 or INDEX=2 (INDEX=3 is out of intereset). At the same time VALUE of PROPERTY should be selected from INDEX=2 if it exists otherwise - from INDEX=1 i.e. I expect 3 properties in result set: p1=v1, p2=v2, p3=v3a

How to compose SQL query (SQL Server and Oracle) for such task without using full outer join?

Answer (score 0):

I see.  You want the result set to have one row for each `Property`, only from indexes 1 and 2, with preference given to 2 when there are duplicates.

You can do this using window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by property order by index desc) as seqnum
      from table t
      where index in (1, 2)
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can also do this using `union all`:

```
select *
from table t
where index = 2
union all
select *
from table t
where index = 1 and
      not exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.property = t.property and t2.index = 2);
```

By the way, `index` is a lousy name for a column because it is a reserved word.

Comment: Second query doesn't work as expected, it returns 4 rows instead of 3.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the suggested answer to select union of all PROPERTY you can write as:

```
;with cte as
(
    select row_number() over ( partition by PROPERTY order by [INDEX] desc) 
    as rownum,
    PROPERTY,VALUE
    from Test 
    where [INDEX] in (1,2)
 )
SELECT top 1 STUFF(
               (SELECT      ',' + cte1.PROPERTY + '=' + cte1.VALUE
               FROM      cte AS cte1
               WHERE      cte1.rownum = cte.rownum 
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS PROPERTY

FROM cte
where rownum = 1
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/NKP65047)</kbd>